# dynamic updating of ordered factors with two numerical components R

Tags: r, string, time-series

I am building a shiny app that is working beautifully except for the nit-picky aesthetic aspects of the user interface. I am trying to select the season to display but in the proper order and R insists on alphabetizing the strings rather than sticking to the temporal order. It might be easier to use data in the form of dates, but I feel like I would still run into the alphabetizing thing I don't want to happen. The data that indicate the seasons is a character string of numbers with the first four representing the year, and the last two digits representing the season where "20" indicates Spring, "30" indicates Summer, and "40" indicates fall. You can generate the values using:

```
seasons<-as.factor(sapply(2000:2019,paste0,c(20,30,40)))
```

You can create a new object of the character string value of the season with:

```
season.string<-factor(paste0(ifelse(substr(seasons,5,6)=="20","Spring ",
                                                 ifelse(substr(seasons,5,6)=="30","Summer ","Fall ")),
                      substr(seasons,1,4)),ordered = T)
```

The problem is that it reorders to indicate that Fall 2001 is earlier than Spring 2000. I want to set up this app to run without a hitch when new seasons are added to the data, and I don't want to have to go in and explicitly call out the new factor level every new season that gets added to the data just so the app will look pretty. Is there a way to coerce R to ignore the alphabetizing without explicitly calling out every factor level and the order they come in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the factor levels instead of the factor itself

```
seasons <- factor(sapply(2000:2019, paste0, c(20, 30, 40)), ordered = TRUE)

levels(seasons) <- 
  paste0(ifelse(substr(levels(seasons), 5, 6) == "20", "Spring ", 
                ifelse(substr(levels(seasons), 5, 6) == "30", "Summer ", "Fall ")),
         substr(levels(seasons), 1, 4))
```

or you can specify the levels you'd like to have for you factor like this

```
season.string <- 
  paste0(ifelse(substr(seasons, 5, 6) == "20", "Spring ", 
                ifelse(substr(seasons, 5, 6) == "30", "Summer ", "Fall ")),
         substr(seasons, 1, 4))

factor(season.string, ordered = T, levels = unique(season.string))
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you so much. Data types are still vexing, but this was a really simple